# I am an Indian and currently holding a 1 year Dutch Living Permit. Can I enter the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, europe, netherlands

I am an Indian citizen currently living in the Netherlands. I have a 1 year Dutch residence permit, can I enter the UK without a separate visa?

Comment: What @HankyPanky said.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. From Timatic:

> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions:
>
> - Nationals of India arriving from Ireland (Rep.) with a valid biometric C visa endorsed "BC BIVS" issued by Ireland (Rep.). The
>     passport must include a valid Irish entry stamp. Passengers are
>     permitted to stay in the United Kingdom until the expiry date of the
>     Irish entry stamp.
> - Passengers with a "Permanent Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union Citizen" or a "Residence Card of a Family Member of a Union
>     Citizen" issued by Netherlands to family members of a national of
>     Switzerland or an EEA Member State . They must travel with or travel
>     to join the national of Switzerland or EEA Member State. **This does
>     not apply to passengers with a different type of residence permit.**
> - Passengers with an EEA Family Permit issued by the United Kingdom if the holder is traveling with, or to join the EEA or Swiss national.